# Jboss EAP5 fails to start on Linux

Tags: linux, jboss

I am trying to start JBoss EAP5 server on Linux CentOs machine. However, the process gets killed abruptly and I get nothing in the boot.logs. Please find the logs below:

```
Server Library URL: file:/usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
Server Log Dir: /usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/log
Server Native Dir: /usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/native
Server Temp Dir: /usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp
Server Temp Deploy Dir: /usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy
Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
./run.sh: line 305: 24103 Killed                  "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$JBOSS_CLASSPATH" org.jboss.Main "$@"
```

below is the dmesg log generated:

```
Linux version 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon May 21 23:36:36 UTC 2018
Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=9abcf354-26a1-485f-9bb7-3df21c74031c ro crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map
NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
efi: EFI v2.40 by HP
ACPI=0x7b7fe000 ACPI 2.0=0x7b7fe014 SMBIOS=0x788db000
SMBIOS 2.8 present.
DMI: HP ProLiant DL160 Gen9/ProLiant DL160 Gen9, BIOS U20 02/17/2017
last_pfn = 0x880000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
MTRR default type: write-back
MTRR fixed ranges enabled
MTRR variable ranges enabled
last_pfn = 0x7b800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Base memory trampoline at [ffff8a8140099000] 99000 size 24576
Using GB pages for direct mapping
RAMDISK:
Early table checksum verification disabled
Local APIC address 0xfee00000
SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0
NUMA: Initialized distance table, cnt=1
NODE_DATA(0) allocated
Reserving 162MB of memory at 720MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 32510MB)
Movable zone start for each node
Initmem setup node 0
On node 0 totalpages: 8322589
tboot: non-0 tboot_addr but it is not of type E820_RESERVED
ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb000020 (or later)
smpboot: Allowing 40 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is 330)
Intel PMU driver.
. version: 3
. bit width: 48
. generic registers: 4
. value mask: 0000ffffffffffff
. max period: 00007fffffffffff
. fixed-purpose events: 3
. event mask: 000000070000000f
NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
Brought up 40 CPUs
smpboot: Max logical packages: 2
smpboot: Total of 40 processors activated (175789.52 BogoMIPS)
node 0 initialised, 7202666 pages in 138ms
devtmpfs: initialized
EVM: security.selinux
EVM: security.ima
EVM: security.capability
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge
acpi PNP0A03:01: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
acpi PNP0A03:01: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:ff
pci_bus 0000:ff: root bus resource [bus ff]
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge
_OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
_OSC: platform does not support [AER]
_OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME PCIeCapability]
FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: on NUMA node 0
[LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI1] (domain 0000 [bus 80-fe])
_OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
_OSC: platform does not support [AER]
_OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME PCIeCapability]
FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:80
pci_bus 0000:80: on NUMA node 0
vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:01:00.1,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
vgaarb: loaded
vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:01:00.1
SCSI subsystem initialized
ACPI: bus type USB registered
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
Initializing
domain hash size = 128
protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
unlabeled traffic allowed by default
at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
8 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
amd_nb: Cannot enumerate AMD northbridges
Switched to clocksource hpet
pnp: PnP ACPI init
ACPI: bus type PNP registered
pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 3 devices
ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
BAR 6: assigned
PCI bridge to [bus 0a]
bridge window [io 0x3000-0x3fff]
bridge window
PCI bridge to [bus 04]
BAR 6: assigned
BAR 6: no space for
BAR 6: failed to assign
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 262144 bind 65536)
TCP: reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 16384 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 16384 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
pci 0000:00:14.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
pci 0000:01:00.1: Boot video device
PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
Unpacking initramfs.
Freeing initrd memory: 27492k freed
PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
software IO TLB(64MB) mapped at [ffff8a819ef41000-ffff8a81a2f40fff]
RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-16 Joules
sha1_ssse3: Using AVX2 optimized SHA-1 implementation
sha256_ssse3: Using AVX2 optimized SHA-256 implementation
futex hash table entries: 16384 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Initialise system trusted keyring
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1531813298.827:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 1 GB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
zpool: loaded
zbud: loaded
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
msgmni has been set to 32768
Key type big_key registered
SELinux: Registering netfilter hooks
NET: Registered protocol family 38
Key type asymmetric registered
Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 248)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered (default)
io scheduler cfq registered
io scheduler mq-deadline registered
io scheduler kyber registered
pcieport: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
pcieport: PCI INT A: no GSI
pcieport: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
pcieport: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
pcieport: PCI INT A: no GSI
pcieport: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
pcieport: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
pci 0000:0a:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
pcieport: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
pcie_pme:pcie001: service driver pcie_pme loaded
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
efifb: probing for efifb
efifb: framebuffer at 0x91000000, mapped to 0xffffa24083800000, using 3072k, total 3072k
efifb: mode is 1024x768x32, linelength=4096, pages=1
efifb: scrolling: redraw
efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x2120
intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x4F
intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
ERST: Error Record Serialization Table (ERST) support is initialized.
pstore: Registered erst as persistent store backend
GHES: APEI firmware first mode is enabled by APEI bit and WHEA _OSC.
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
00:02: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.1
rdac: device handler registered
hp_sw: device handler registered
emc: device handler registered
alua: device handler registered
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
ehci-pci: EHCI Host Controller
ehci-pci: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ehci-pci: debug port 2
ehci-pci: cache line size of 64 is not supported
ehci-pci: irq 18, io mem 0x93002000
ehci-pci: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
i8042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042
i8042: probe of i8042 failed with error -5
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
rtc_cmos 00:00: RTC can wake from S4
rtc_cmos 00:00: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
rtc_cmos 00:00: alarms up to one month, y3k, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
cpuidle: using governor menu
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
TCP: cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 10
NET: Registered protocol family 17
mpls_gso: MPLS GSO support
microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 
PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux kpatch signing key: 
Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux Driver update signing key: 
Loaded X.509 cert 'CentOS Linux kernel signing key:
registered taskstats version 1
Key type trusted registered
Key type encrypted registered
IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass! (rc=-19)
Magic number: 10:157:673
rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2018-07-17 07:41:40 UTC (1531813300)
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1832k freed
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
Freeing unused kernel memory: 852k freed
Freeing unused kernel memory: 680k freed
systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Detected architecture x86-64.
Running in initial RAM disk.
Set hostname to <localhost.localdomain>.
Created slice Root Slice.
Starting Root Slice.
Listening on udev Control Socket.
Starting udev Control Socket.
Created slice System Slice.
Starting System Slice.
Listening on Journal Socket.
Starting Journal Socket.
Starting Setup Virtual Console.
Reached target Timers.
Starting Timers.
Reached target Slices.
Starting Slices.
Reached target Swap.
Starting Swap.
Starting dracut cmdline hook.
Starting Apply Kernel Variables.
Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
Starting Journal Service.
Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
Starting udev Kernel Socket.
Reached target Sockets.
Starting Sockets.
Reached target Local File Systems.
Starting Local File Systems.
Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Started Setup Virtual Console.
Started Journal Service.
dca service started, version 1.12.1
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
HP HPSA Driver (v 3.4.20-0-RH2)
hpsa 0000:0a:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
hpsa 0000:0a:00.0: Logical aborts not supported
libata version 3.00 loaded.
igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.4.0-k
igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
ahci: version 3.0
ahci: enabling device (0406 -> 0407)
ahci: irq 93 for MSI/MSI-X
ahci: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl RAID mode
ahci: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pio slum part ems apst
ahci: enabling device (0406 -> 0407)
ahci: irq 94 for MSI/MSI-X
ahci: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x3f impl RAID mode
ahci: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pio slum part ems apst
ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x93000000 port 0x93000280 irq 94
ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x93000000 port 0x93000300 irq 94
ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x93000000 port 0x93000380 irq 94
hpsa: scsi: added RAID HP H240 controller SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
hpsa: scsi: masked Direct-Access ATA WDC WD10JFCX-68N PHYS DRV SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=0
hpsa: scsi: added Direct-Access HP LOGICAL VOLUME RAID-1(+0) SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
scsi: RAID HP H240 5.52 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
checking generic (91000000 300000) vs hw (91000000 1000000)
fb: conflicting fb hw usage mgag200drmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2197.428 MHz
Switched to clocksource tsc
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input1
Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[TTM] Zone kernel: Available graphics memory: 16256006 kiB
[TTM] Zone dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
igb: added PHC on eth0
igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
igb: eth0: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) 98:f2:b3:f1:f5:02
igb: eth0: PBA No: 0960FF-0FF
igb: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
scsi: Direct-Access HP LOGICAL VOLUME 5.52 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
fbcon: mgadrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input2
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2660
usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
hub 4-3:1.0: USB hub found
hub 4-3:1.0: 2 ports detected
igb: added PHC on eth1
igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
igb: eth1: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) 98:f2:b3:f1:f5:03
igb: eth1: PBA No: 0960FF-0FF
igb: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
mgag200 0000:01:00.1: fb0: mgadrmfb frame buffer device
[drm] Initialized mgag200 1.0.0 20110418 for 0000:01:00.1 on minor 0
ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata10: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
sd: [sda] 3906917808 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
sd: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
sd: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd: [sda] Mode Sense: 73 00 00 08
sd: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
random: fast init done
sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5
sd: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
random: crng init done
systemd-journald[308]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
SELinux: Disabled at runtime.
SELinux: Unregistering netfilter hooks
type=1404 audit(1531813302.815:2): selinux=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ip_tables'
TCP: bic registered
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
systemd-journald[660]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
pcc-cpufreq: (v1.10.00) driver loaded with frequency limits: 1200 MHz, 2200 MHz
wmi: Mapper loaded
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
ipmi message handler version 39.2
ipmi device interface
ioatdma: Intel(R) QuickData Technology Driver 4.00
ioatdma 0000:00:04.0: irq 115 for MSI/MSI-X
igb: DCA enabled
igb: DCA enabled
ioatdma: irq 133 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma: irq 134 for MSI/MSI-X
ioatdma: irq 135 for MSI/MSI-X
ipmi_si IPI0001:00: ipmi_si: probing via ACPI
ipmi_si IPI0001:00: [io 0x0ca2-0x0ca3] regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
ipmi_si: Adding ACPI-specified kcs state machine
IPMI System Interface driver.
ipmi_si: probing via SMBIOS
ipmi_si: SMBIOS: io 0xca2 regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
(NULL device *): SMBIOS-specified kcs state machine: duplicate
ipmi_si: probing via SPMI
ipmi_si: SPMI: io 0xca3 regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
ipmi_si: Adding SPMI-specified kcs state machine
ipmi_si: Trying ACPI-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x20, irq 0
input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
scsi: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 12
sd: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
hpwdt: HPE Watchdog Timer Driver: NMI decoding initialized, allow kernel dump: ON (default = 1/ON)
hpwdt: HPE Watchdog Timer Driver: 1.4.0, timer margin: 30 seconds (nowayout=0).
iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
ipmi_si IPI0001:00: Found new BMC (man_id: 0x00000b, prod_id: 0x2000, dev_id: 0x13)
ipmi_si IPI0001:00: IPMI kcs interface initialized
iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
iTCO_wdt: unable to reset NO_REBOOT flag, device disabled by hardware/BIOS
IPMI SSIF Interface driver
cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 100
AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
alg: No test for __generic-gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-generic-gcm-aes-aesni)
perf: interrupt took too long (3891 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 51000
intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
intel_rapl: DRAM domain energy unit 15300pj
intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
EDAC MC0: Giving out device to 'sbridge_edac.c' 'Broadwell Socket#0': DEV 0000:7f:12.0
EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for sbridge_edac.c Broadwell Socket#0: DEV 0000:7f:12.0
EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
Adding 10485756k swap on /dev/sda5. Priority:-1 extents:1 across:10485756k FS
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.37.0-ioctl (2017-09-20) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno2: link is not ready
igb 0000:05:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
perf: interrupt took too long (5040 > 4863), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39000
ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Ebtables v2.0 registered
bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max <>
virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered blocking state
virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
device virbr0-nic entered promiscuous mode
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered blocking state
virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state
fuse init (API version 7.22)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
igb 0000:05:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
igb 0000:05:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0001: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
usb 3-1: Manufacturer: BMC
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input4
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input5
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
perf: interrupt took too long (7721 > 6300), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0003: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
usb 3-1: Manufacturer: BMC
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input6
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input7
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0005: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
perf: interrupt took too long (9719 > 9651), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 20000
TCP: lp registered
UDP: bad checksum. From 218.75.40.148:16847 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): virbr0: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
UDP: bad checksum. From 218.75.37.18:2585 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
UDP: bad checksum. From 218.75.37.18:2585 to 172.22.16.10:161 ulen 49
perf: interrupt took too long (12569 > 12148), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 15000
UDP: bad checksum. From 60.191.0.245:2585 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
UDP: bad checksum. From 218.75.40.147:16847 to 172.22.16.10:161 ulen 49
UDP: bad checksum. From 122.224.158.196:16847 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
perf: interrupt took too long (16463 > 15711), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 12000
perf: interrupt took too long (20930 > 20578), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 9000
perf: interrupt took too long (27562 > 26162), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 7000
UDP: bad checksum. From 60.191.0.244:62674 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
sh[15222]: segfault at 63 ip 00007f794c4cc60d sp 00007f78dfffe520 error 4 in libnss_files-2.17.so[7f794c4c9000+c000]
UDP: bad checksum. From 122.224.158.197:60504 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
sh[15451]: segfault at 63 ip 00007f08605e960d sp 00007f08067fb520 error 4 in libnss_files-2.17.so[7f08605e6000+c000]
sh[18006]: segfault at 63 ip 00007f1a4c3eb60d sp 00007f1a097f9520 error 4 in libnss_files-2.17.so[7f1a4c3e8000+c000]
lib64[11782]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004579d6 sp 00007fffb3284df0 error 4 in lib64[400000+59000]
lib64[12598]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004579d6 sp 00007ffe72fdd590 error 4 in lib64[400000+59000]
lib64[13307]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004579d6 sp 00007ffccb13df10 error 4 in lib64[400000+59000]
UDP: bad checksum. From 60.191.23.61:60504 to 172.22.16.10:53 ulen 37
hpwdt: Unexpected close, not stopping watchdog!
hrtimer: interrupt took 436492 ns
watchbog[6418]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004891f0 sp 00007ffe6fdf2e08 error 6 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
watchbog[36712]:segfault at 0 ip 0000000000507990 sp 00007ffd9b4f7b28 error 6 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
traps: watchbog[5982] general protection ip:5ab001 sp:7e7ae0 error:0 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
watchbog[32463]:segfault at 0 ip 00000000004891f0 sp 00007ffde96f9268 error 6 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
watchbog[30688]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000507990 sp 00007ffe058ff008 error 6 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
usb 3-1: Manufacturer: BMC
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input8
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input9
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0008: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0007: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
watchbog[8805]: segfault at 5967fe ip 00000000005b3000 sp 00007ffd932f6af8 error 7 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
traps: watchbog[6411] trap invalid opcode ip:5b7000 sp:7ffd18e38578 error:0 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
watchbog[18918]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000507990 sp 00007ffddef291f8 error 6 in watchbog[400000+1e2000]
usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=7029
usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-1: Product: Virtual Keyboard
usb 3-1: Manufacturer: BMC
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input10
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input0
input: BMC Virtual Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:01:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input11
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [BMC Virtual Keyboard ] on usb-0000:01:00.4-1/input1
usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
hid-generic 0003:03F0:7029.0009: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
```

kindly help. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Check `dmesg`. And please share the basic information about the server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank  you for your reply. Please find the edit with dmesg logs. Kindly let me know if I accidentally removed something from the logs that you want. Also, I would appreciate if you would educate me about the debugging procedure.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, as I can see with `top` command on my server and as well as in `dmesg` logs, there is a `watchbog` process running on it. As I could understand from info gathered from internet, `watchbog` is a malware. Can it be a reason behind the issue I am experiencing?

Comment: I think you have multiple problems. The system isn't up to date. The server needs a BIOS update. You probably have bad RAM or a bad motherboard. And you also probably have malware.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - thank you for the information. I have informed my friend working on Linux for the project and he is working on it. I am more interested in Jboss issue that what could be the probable cause behind the process getting killed. May you please help me with it as well?

Comment: Most likely that's a result of the bad RAM/bad motherboard.

Comment: @Micheal Hampton Thank you for your response. We followed what you suggested, updated linux OS, applied all the patches, restarted the server and ran a scan on the machine. This fixed the other issues and now jboss is running fine as well. Thank you for all your help. Much appreciated.